# php remote debug xdebug on iis cgi timeout

Tags: php, debugging, cgi, configuration-files

I'm successfully debugging PHP from a remote machine. My only problem is the cgi timeout after 30 seconds.

What do I modify and where? I googled a little and found a config file everyone talking about but I don't have it in my system32.

How do I make this timeout be at least 10 minutes? Where is the cgi config?

Answer (score 1):

You've set your max_execution_time in php.ini to more than 30?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

To find your php.ini file, you can create a php script containing

```
<?php
phpinfo()
```

Then search the results for "php.ini", you should get an idea of where PHP is looking to find the file.

From a quick google, IIS timeout is supposedly set to 5 minutes by default so that should not be the issue (unless it was changed at some point).